# Simple Javascript thing about variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables, 2d-games

I am following a tutorial and in it he declares variables and then proceeds to do something else with them that i do not understand.

```
var player, ai, ball;

player = { // this is the code I am referring to
    x: null,
    y: null,
    width: 20,
    height: 100,

    update: function(){},
    draw: function(){
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
};
```

Is he adding variables inside a variable?
Thanks.

Comment: Read a basic tutorial on JavaScript data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's declaring a javascript object.

You could probably use some [reading](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

> Objects are variables too. But objects can contain many values.

Comment: Thanks for you help I now get it.

Answer (score 0):

This code assigns an object to the variable. The string on the left-hand side of each colon is a property name. The code assigns values to the properties, the last two of which assign functions to be called.

The properties can be called like so:

```
   var playerAge = player.age;
```

The functions would similarly be called:

```
   player.draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for you help I now get it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly just setting variables within a variable. He's setting `player` equal to a Javascript object. This object contains members like `x` and `y`, and the functions `update` and `draw`.

[JS Object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: Thanks for your help, one quick one the member( or elements) are they defined by Javascript or could I go and call it MyX, MyY ?

Comment: Technically, these are not called members. Common usage would be to call them properties.

Answer (score -1):

```
var player, ai, ball;  // this declare variables 

player = { // player = {} , it means player is a object
    x: null,    // this object have a var call x;
    y: null,
    width: 20,  
    height: 100, 

    // this object has a property "update", and update is a function;
    update: function(){},  

    // this object has a property "draw", and draw is a function;
    draw: function(){
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you help I now get it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `this object have var update`. `update` is not a variable here, it's a property, which is a very different thing.